# Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$ distinct roots. Show $p''(x)p(x) - (p'(x)^2)$ has no real roots.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials

If the question is not clear, here's an example. Let $p(x) := (x-1)(x-2) = x^2-3x+2$. Taking first and second derivatives, we get
\begin{align*}
   p'(x) &= 2x -3
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
   p''(x) &= 2.
\end{align*}
Substituting these polynomials into the equation above we get
\begin{align*}
    p''(x)p(x) - (p'(x))^2 &= 2x^2-6x+4 - (2x-3)^2. 
\end{align*}

Which has roots $\frac{3}{2} \pm\frac{1}{2}i$ neither which are real. In the degree 2 case, it seems like $p''(x)p(x) - (p'(x))^2$ will always be another quadratic whose roots are complex, so it really comes down to showing that the discriminant is negative. Doing the computation for the polynomial
\begin{align*}
p(x) := (x-a)(x-b) = x^2-(a+b)x+ab
\end{align*}
we can call $c = a+b$ and computing derivatives we get
\begin{align*}
   p'(x) &= 2x -c
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
   p''(x) &= 2.
\end{align*}. Substituting into our equation above, we get the simplification
\begin{align*}
-2x^2 + 2cx + (2ab-c).
\end{align*}
Using the quadratic formula, our roots are
\begin{align*}
x =\frac{-2c \pm \sqrt{2c^2-4(-2)(2ab-c)}}{-4}
\end{align*}
and substituting $a + b$ in for $c$, we get
\begin{align*}
x= \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2(a+b)^2-4(-2)(2ab-(a+b))}}{2}
\end{align*}
Which the real part of $x$ aligns perfectly with our example above. My issue is, how do I go about showing the discriminant is negative for arbitrary values $a$ and $b$? Furthermore, how do I show this generalizes to $n$ degrees?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): **Your question should be clear without the title.**  After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: In your final formula for $x$, if $a=0, b=-1$, you get real roots.

Comment: You made a mistake. The simplification doesn't give us $-2x^2 + 2cx + (2ab-c)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_k$ be the real distinct roots, then $p(x) = a\prod_{k=1}^n (x-x_k)$ and:

$$
\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-x_k} \;\;\implies\;\; \frac{p''(x)p(x)-(p'(x))^2}{p^2(x)} = \left(\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}\right)' = - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(x-x_k)^2} \lt 0
$$

It follows that the LHS numerator $\,p''(x)p(x)-(p'(x))^2 \ne 0\,$ on $\,\mathbb R \setminus \{x_k\}\,$. Since all roots are distinct $\,p'(x_k) \ne 0\,$ so $\,p''(x)p(x)-(p'(x))^2 \ne 0\,$ on the whole $\,\mathbb R\,$.

Comment: Don't you need a separate argument to rule out the possibility that a zero of the original polynomial is also a zero of $p''p-(p')^2$?  That's where you need that the roots are distinct.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, I was just editing that in.